# Pagination withOUT jQuery. How can I select a range of elements with the same class? Does my logic make any sense?

Tags: javascript, html, pagination

I am working on a project and I want to create a pagination feature for a list of students. There are 54 students and I want to show no more than 10 per page.

The class of the list (`ul`) itself is `"student-list"` and the class of the individual students (`li`) is `"student-item"`.

Of course, I also need to create buttons at the bottom of the page to link to the respective pages.

My intuition tells me to link each button to a number. If that button is pressed then it will display the required range of students.

I want to do this by setting all the `student-item`'s as hidden. Based on the button clicked, I can then set a certain range of the `student-item`'s to visible. How can I do this? Is this possible without jQuery?

Here is my pseudocode. Please do not give too much away!:

```
//Problem: Shows too many people per page
//Solution: Incorporate pagination and add search functionality

var studentTotal = document.getElementsByClassName("student-item").length;
var pageCount = Math.ceil(studentTotal/10);
var pageNum;
var buttonNum = pageCount;

console.log(studentTotal);
console.log(pageCount);


//Add pagination feature


    var displayPage = function() {
        //Display first 10 students on initial page view, first 10 .student-items OF .studentList
        //Hide all but first 10 students when the page loads
        var divsToshow = document.getElementsByClassName("student-item");

        //Display buttons
        createButton();

        //active button = page number
    }   

    //Create enough buttons for amount of page numbers
    var createButton = function() {


        //add button list div, .pagination with an unordered list 
        //Create a button(li) for every page number
    }


    //Bind eventhandler to button action to display page
    var bindButton = function() {

    }


    //If user clicks on 2 in pagination, students 11-20 are shown etc.
    var buttonClick = function() {
        //Simple animation when transitioning between pages

        //call displayPage
        displayPage();
    }
```

Here is my html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Students</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/design.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page">
      <div class="page-header cf">
        <h2>Students</h2>
      </div>
      <ul class="student-list">
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/67.jpg">
                <h3>iboya vat</h3>
                <span class="email">iboya.vat@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/15/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/75.jpg">
                <h3>aapo niskanen</h3>
                <span class="email">aapo.niskanen@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/15/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/34.jpg">
                <h3>phillip cox</h3>
                <span class="email">phillip.cox@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/11/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/38.jpg">
                <h3>zilda moreira</h3>
                <span class="email">zilda.moreira@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/15/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/23.jpg">
                <h3>lilou le gall</h3>
                <span class="email">lilou.le gall@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/16/13</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/94.jpg">
                <h3>lucy hall</h3>
                <span class="email">lucy.hall@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/11/16</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/24.jpg">
                <h3>mark colin</h3>
                <span class="email">mark.colin@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 01/14/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/14.jpg">
                <h3>sara alves</h3>
                <span class="email">sara.alves@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/19/16</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/49.jpg">
                <h3>ramon macrae</h3>
                <span class="email">ramon.macrae@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/13/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/15.jpg">
                <h3>connor taylor</h3>
                <span class="email">connor.taylor@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/18/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/11.jpg">
                <h3>aymeric morel</h3>
                <span class="email">aymeric.morel@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/13/13</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/49.jpg">
                <h3>lorenz otto</h3>
                <span class="email">lorenz.otto@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/11/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/29.jpg">
                <h3>karl williamson</h3>
                <span class="email">karl.williamson@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 01/12/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/34.jpg">
                <h3>ouassim heering</h3>
                <span class="email">ouassim.heering@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 01/18/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/91.jpg">
                <h3>roberto molina</h3>
                <span class="email">roberto.molina@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/13/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/28.jpg">
                <h3>jordan hubert</h3>
                <span class="email">jordan.hubert@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/13/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/29.jpg">
                <h3>melvin baker</h3>
                <span class="email">melvin.baker@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/18/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/26.jpg">
                <h3>everett gordon</h3>
                <span class="email">everett.gordon@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/17/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/82.jpg">
                <h3>aiden ma</h3>
                <span class="email">aiden.ma@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/18/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/62.jpg">
                <h3>florent gerard</h3>
                <span class="email">florent.gerard@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 02/12/13</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/96.jpg">
                <h3>amber chen</h3>
                <span class="email">amber.chen@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/12/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/9.jpg">
                <h3>alexandra davies</h3>
                <span class="email">alexandra.davies@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/11/13</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/57.jpg">
                <h3>sergio cole</h3>
                <span class="email">sergio.cole@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 02/17/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/98.jpg">
                <h3>edgar dixon</h3>
                <span class="email">edgar.dixon@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/17/11</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/94.jpg">
                <h3>kirk myers</h3>
                <span class="email">kirk.myers@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/17/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/28.jpg">
                <h3>ani hesseling</h3>
                <span class="email">ani.hesseling@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 08/14/16</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/24.jpg">
                <h3>victoire bonnet</h3>
                <span class="email">victoire.bonnet@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/13/16</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/44.jpg">
                <h3>marcos morales</h3>
                <span class="email">marcos.morales@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 01/12/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/75.jpg">
                <h3>nils neumann</h3>
                <span class="email">nils.neumann@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 03/11/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/86.jpg">
                <h3>emily harrison</h3>
                <span class="email">emily.harrison@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/18/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/41.jpg">
                <h3>matthew fortin</h3>
                <span class="email">matthew.fortin@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 03/18/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/32.jpg">
                <h3>charlotte steward</h3>
                <span class="email">charlotte.steward@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 02/18/11</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/3.jpg">
                <h3>marceau rodriguez</h3>
                <span class="email">marceau.rodriguez@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/13/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/91.jpg">
                <h3>hudson anderson</h3>
                <span class="email">hudson.anderson@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/12/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/33.jpg">
                <h3>warren phillips</h3>
                <span class="email">warren.phillips@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 01/11/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/41.jpg">
                <h3>leo niva</h3>
                <span class="email">leo.niva@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/14/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/3.jpg">
                <h3>hani prevoo</h3>
                <span class="email">hani.prevoo@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 01/11/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/79.jpg">
                <h3>veronica rodriguez</h3>
                <span class="email">veronica.rodriguez@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/17/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/41.jpg">
                <h3>ginestal das neves</h3>
                <span class="email">ginestal.das neves@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/19/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/63.jpg">
                <h3>devon barnes</h3>
                <span class="email">devon.barnes@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/19/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/55.jpg">
                <h3>brennan pierce</h3>
                <span class="email">brennan.pierce@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/15/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/35.jpg">
                <h3>zachary singh</h3>
                <span class="email">zachary.singh@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/19/11</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/35.jpg">
                <h3>arlo harris</h3>
                <span class="email">arlo.harris@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/12/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/60.jpg">
                <h3>hannah ginnish</h3>
                <span class="email">hannah.ginnish@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/17/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/95.jpg">
                <h3>goos brunt</h3>
                <span class="email">goos.brunt@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/15/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/91.jpg">
                <h3>eduard riedel</h3>
                <span class="email">eduard.riedel@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/12/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/42.jpg">
                <h3>geesken jekel</h3>
                <span class="email">geesken.jekel@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 02/12/13</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/54.jpg">
                <h3>dolores ryan</h3>
                <span class="email">dolores.ryan@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/17/16</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/49.jpg">
                <h3>steven rogers</h3>
                <span class="email">steven.rogers@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 01/18/11</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/63.jpg">
                <h3>virgulino silva</h3>
                <span class="email">virgulino.silva@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 03/18/11</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/11.jpg">
                <h3>lucile bertrand</h3>
                <span class="email">lucile.bertrand@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/13/16</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/10.jpg">
                <h3>elsa lahti</h3>
                <span class="email">elsa.lahti@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 04/15/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/12.jpg">
                <h3>soline leclercq</h3>
                <span class="email">soline.leclercq@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/12/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/89.jpg">
                <h3>henri kruse</h3>
                <span class="email">henri.kruse@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/14/13</span>
           </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="pagination">
      <ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</html>
```

Here is an example of what my pagination html buttons should look like if I were to have 5 buttons:

```
<div class="pagination">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a class="active" href="#">1</a>
          </li>
           <li>
            <a href="#">2</a>
          </li>
           <li>
            <a href="#">3</a>
          </li>
           <li>
            <a href="#">4</a>
          </li>
           <li>
            <a href="#">5</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

VanillaJS to display student items 10-19 and hide the rest:

```
var studentItems = document.querySelectorAll('li.student-item');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(studentItems, function(e, i) {
  e.style.display = (i >= 10 && i < 20) ? 'block' : 'none';
});
```

You can generalise this into a `showPage(page)` function.

Answer (score 0):

I created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jx972fz3/7/) for you

JavaScript

```
var PAGE_STUDENT = 2; // Declare how many studuents to show per page
var studentArray = document.getElementsByClassName("student-item");
var studentNum = studentArray.length; // totle number of students
function displayPage (pageNow) {
  //Display PAGE_STUDENT students according to pageNow
  var i;
  // Hide or show student according to current page
  for (i = 0; i < studentNum; i++) {
    if (i < pageNow * PAGE_STUDENT || i >= (pageNow + 1) * PAGE_STUDENT) {
      studentArray[i].style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      studentArray[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
}

function displayButton () {
  var paginationUl = document.getElementById("paginationList");
  var pages = Math.ceil(studentNum / PAGE_STUDENT); // Calculate total pages
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.onclick = (function (j) { return function () {displayPage(j);} }(i)); // shoe certain page. Use closure to remenber i
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(i + 1); 
    li.appendChild(textnode);
    paginationUl.appendChild(li);
  }
}
// Display initial page, i.e., the first ten student
displayPage(0);
//Display buttons
displayButton();
```

Also, I add a `paginationList` to your ul to simplify codes.

```
<div class="pagination">
    <ul id="paginationList">
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I simplify your logic a bit. I hope I didn't give too much away. Sorry. Didn't think through. Hope it still helps.